# Python gives strange values of factorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial

```
x = 5

def SsolGom():
  k = 1
    for i in range( 1 , x+1 ):
       k = k * i

print(SsolGom)
```

=function SsolGom at 0x00F1B660

120 must come out but strange value came out...

Comment: You haven't called the function.... `print(SsolGom())` and you need to return a result, e.g. `return k` from `SsolGom()`. But you really should just pass `x` in as an argument, `def SsolGom(x): ...` and `print(SsolGcom(5))`. You will also need to fix your formatting `k=1` is incorrectly indented and python will complain.

Comment: Why are you even attempting to write a factorial function if 1) you don't know how to call it; 2) you make it totally useless by _not_ letting it have any arguments (so, you're always be calculating the factorial of the same number)? Please learn some Python first.

Comment: A function should return something back when it is called. Your function is not returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

`SsolGom` is a function, `SsolGom()` is the value returned by this function. It's similar in math: `sin` is a function, `sin(0)` is a number.

```
x = 5

def SsolGom():
    k = 1
    for i in range( 1 , x+1 ):
       k = k * i
    return k

print(SsolGom())
# 120
```

You need to have a correct indentation inside your function, and you need to return a value. `SsolGom()` would be `None` otherwise.

Note that `x` probably shouldn't be a global variable. Otherwise, your function could be replaced by `return 120`:

```
def factorial(x):
    k = 1
    for i in range(x):
       k = k * (i + 1)
    return k

print(factorial(5))
```

Finally, here's the easiest way to get factorial in Python:

```
>>> from math import factorial
>>> factorial(5)
120
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the brackets. It should be:

```
print(SsolGom())
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are printing the function without the parenthesis. Calling a function with and without parenthesis gives different results in Python. If you do not provide a parenthesis, Python considers it as properties and not a method/function. Hence you got that result
2. provide a return statement in the function.

Updated Code:

```
x=5
def SsolGom():
    k=1
    for i in range( 1 , x+1 ):
        k=k*i
    return k

print(SsolGom())
```